# How to read two number(0~99) and multiply and print result

Tags: assembly, multiplication

I use int 21h/ah=1 to read only one number(0~9) and successfully multiply and print result. But how can I read two number and multiply? It is more complex than I thought.

Comment: you read two numbers and multiply. Where do you see a problem? What did you try? How did it fail? Why did you try *that* and what did you expect?

Comment: i read two values of digit in units to subtract them with 30h and finally to add 30h to print it out. i don't know how to multiply two values of digit in tens. does it have another way to think?

Comment: `int 21h` does offer only input/output of characters or bytes, not integers. So what you are using is reading ASCII character, and by doing `-30h` you convert it from single ASCII digit into value 0..9. To get full integer from two characters you can do (digit1-30h)*10 + (digit2-30h) (i.e. string "35" will lead to (3*10+5) = 35.) ... to print out multi-digit integer you have to reverse the process, find out how many hundreds/tens/ones there are in the value (for example by dividing the value by 10), producing single digit values 0..9 .. then you convert them ASCII characters by +30h,then print